# matplotlib legend shows same labels multiple times (using a label vector)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

[Edit: Clarification.]

I want to plot a number of lines, some of which belong to the same material and therefore should have the same color and share the same legend entry.
I have created a names vector for these labels, but matplotlib still assigns a separate legend entry to each line, despite the fact that they share the same name string.
How can I merge the data from one category into one legend entry?

**Example**:
I want the two lines which depict "Treatment" to have the same color and share the same legend entry:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([[1.1, 1.7, 2.2, 3, 4.1, 5.5],
             [1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 4.6, 5],
             [2.5, 3.8, 5.2, 7.3, 8.4, 8.5]])
x = np.linspace(0, 6, num=6)
names = ['Treatment', 'Treatment', 'Control']
for i in range (len(a)):
    plt.plot(x, a[i].T, label=names[i])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: example figure]

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you!  
I should have been more clear, I actually want the curves to be also color coded by their group, i.e. the "treatment" curves should have the same color. Do you know how I would go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (maybe too complicated) way to draw the curves per unique label:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([[1.1, 1.7, 2.2, 3, 4.1, 5.5],
              [1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 4.6, 5],
              [2.5, 3.8, 5.2, 7.3, 8.4, 8.5]])
x = np.linspace(0, 6, num=6)
names = ['Treatment', 'Treatment', 'Control']

unique_names = np.unique(names)
colors = plt.cm.get_cmap('Set1').colors
for unique_name, color in zip(unique_names, colors):
    label = unique_name
    for ai, name in zip(a, names):
        if name == unique_name:
            plt.plot(x, ai.T, label=label, color=color)
            label = None  # set to None when used once
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]